# Flutter Information Does not want to appear on screen

Tags: flutter

I want to print the results from the results I get from the results method, now it returns nothing on the screen. May I please get help on where am I wrong. This is my code below

```
class BarcodeItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  BarcodeItem item;

  BarcodeItemWidget(this.item);

    String results(){
      String result = "";
    if( barcodeFormatEnumMap[item.barcodeFormat]! == "pdf_417"){
         result = "MVL code:" + item.text.split('%')[1] ;
    }else{ if (barcodeFormatEnumMap[item.barcodeFormat]! == "code_128"){
      result = "item code:" + item.text ;
    }

    }

    return result;

}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[

          Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text("Barcode Type:",
                  style: TextStyle(inherit: true, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  barcodeFormatEnumMap[item.barcodeFormat]!,
                  style: TextStyle(inherit: true, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),

          Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                    results()
                ),
              ),
```

may someone please see what I am not doing right. Thank you

Comment: what do you get from `barcodeFormatEnumMap[item.barcodeFormat]!` ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi everyone I found the issue. The way item.barcodeFormat is declared like PDF_417 and I used pdf_417, so that was it. Thank you

I just need one more thing, it only prints one line and I want to print many lines with all that info, may u please assist check my updated code below

```
 String results(){
      String result = "";
    if( barcodeFormatEnumMap[item.barcodeFormat]! == 'PDF_417'){
         result = "MVL code:" + item.text.split('%')[1] ;
         result = "Auth code:" + item.text.split('%')[2] ;
         result = "License Number:" + item.text.split('%')[3] ;
         result = "Issue Number:" + item.text.split('%')[4] ;
         result = "Disc Number:" + item.text.split('%')[5] ;
         result = "License Plate:" + item.text.split('%')[6] ;
         result = "Vehicle Registration:" + item.text.split('%')[7] ;
         result = "Vehicle Type:" + item.text.split('%')[8] ;
         result = "Make:" + item.text.split('%')[9] ;
         result = "Model:" + item.text.split('%')[10] ;
         result = "Colour:" + item.text.split('%')[11] ;
         result = "Vin Number:" + item.text.split('%')[12] ;
         result = "Engine Number:" + item.text.split('%')[13] ;
         result = "Disk Expiry:" + item.text.split('%')[14] ;

    }else{ if (barcodeFormatEnumMap[item.barcodeFormat]! == 'CODE_128'){
      result = "item code:" + item.text ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a debug point on the line you are calling `results()` or better try add a variable `String result = results();` inside your `build` method so you can see if the value returned from `results()` is correct..

Then if it is correct the problem is with the widget you are displaying.. it can be size, position, color etc..